# Resize ApplicationWindow from Qml

Tags: qt, qml

I encountered a bad performance of my implementation of ResizeArea, please help me to speed up...
How I would use :

```
 ApplicationWindow {
    id: rootWindow
    width: 1280
    height: 768
    minimumHeight: 768
    minimumWidth: 1280
    visible: true
    flags: Qt.FramelessWindowHint | Qt.CustomizeWindowHint
    ResizeArea{
        height: parent.height
        anchors.left: parent.left
        anchors.leftMargin: 0
        width: 3
    }
    }
```

`ResizeArea.qml`:

```
MouseArea {
    id: mr
    cursorShape: Qt.SizeHorCursor
    property int clickPosX
    onPressed: {
        clickPosX  = mouseX

    }

    onPositionChanged: {
        rootWindow.setWidth(rootWindow.width+(mouseX-clickPosX))
    }
}
```

It works, but slowly.
I think implementation with `dragItem` should be faster, but I don't know how to write it.

Comment: I have had some lags there: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14236386/performance-qml-window-repaints-himself-very-slow but guys in IRC have said me that X11 sucks and MacOS roolez. No idea why but I was very sad about it.